# How to go get ubuntu launchpad/bazaar packages?

Tags: ubuntu, go, launchpad

I'm trying to go get http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-push-hackers/ubuntu-push/trunk/view/head:/bus/networkmanager

I've tried :
go get bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-push-hackers/ubuntu-push/bus/networkmanager

```
package bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-push-hackers/ubuntu-push/bus/networkmanager: unrecognized import path "bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-push-hackers/ubuntu-push/bus/networkmanager"
```

go get bazaar.launchpad.net/ubuntu-push-hackers/ubuntu-push/bus/networkmanager

```
Same result as above
```

go get launchpad.net/ubuntu-push-hackers/ubuntu-push/bus/networkmanager

```
# cd .; bzr branch https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-push-hackers /root/go/src/launchpad.net/ubuntu-push-hackers
bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-push-hackers/".
package launchpad.net/ubuntu-push-hackers/ubuntu-push/bus/networkmanager: exit status 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `go get` you work on packages and not on git refs or file system paths.

Try

```
go get launchpad.net/ubuntu-push
```

Comment: I get a lot of compilation errors[0], most likely from other "subpackages". I'm wondering if it's possible to get only the networkmanager package not the whole repository. That  seems possible on git / github. http://pastebin.com/LNmSCfxJ

Comment: sorry for the noise... it seems to work after all. go get launchpad.net/ubuntu-push/bus/networkmanager

Comment: My fault. I could have noticed that you are only interested in the networkmanager package.